# How to do cupyx distributed matrix multiplication

Tags: cupy

Can someone provide an example of how to do distributed sparse matrix multiplication with cupyx on an MPI cluster with 4 gpus per node. I cannot find this in the documentation. Thanks.

The below example runs on every process and is not distrobuted:

```
from cupyx.scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import cupy as cp

sv = cp.array([initial_state_circuit.get_statevector()]).T

sv_sparse = csr_matrix(sv)
print('uploading sv')

op_sparse = csr_matrix(qubit_ham_hubbard.to_sparse_matrix())
print('uploading op')

sv_expval = (sv_sparse.conj().T @ op_sparse @ sv_sparse)[0,0]
print('sv_expval', sv_expval)
```